# Add items to list programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, client-object-model

I would like to create a menu from the listtemplate Promoted Links, with several tiles. I use the following code to create the list, and create new list items:

```
ListTemplate listTemplate = web.ListTemplates.GetByName("Promoted Links"); 

        context.Load(listTemplate);

        // Execute the query to the server
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        // Create a new object for ListCreationInformation class - used to specify the properties of the new list
        ListCreationInformation creationInfo = new ListCreationInformation();

        // TITEL
        creationInfo.Title = "KlasseSite menu"; 
        // description
        creationInfo.Description = "Tile menu";
        creationInfo.TemplateFeatureId = listTemplate.FeatureId;
        creationInfo.TemplateType = listTemplate.ListTemplateTypeKind;
        web.Lists.Add(creationInfo);

        context.ExecuteQuery();  

        // new list item
        List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("KlasseSite menu"); 
        ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
        ListItem newItem = announcementsList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

        newItem["Title"] = "SkoleSite"; newItem["LinkLocation"] = "/sites/Engelsk";
        newItem["Title"] = "Settings"; newItem["LinkLocation"] = "/sites/Engelsk/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx";
        newItem.Update();

        context.ExecuteQuery();
```

My problem:
This code only creates one tile, because

```
newItem["Title"] = "Settings"; newItem["LinkLocation"] = "/sites/Engelsk/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx";
```

Overwrites:

```
newItem["Title"] = "SkoleSite"; newItem["LinkLocation"] = "/sites/Engelsk";
```

How can i add to several rows in the list?

Answer (score 3):

Change the code that creates the items to the following:

```
var itemData = new [,] { { "SkoleSite", "/sites/Engelsk" }, { "Settings", "/sites/Engelsk/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx" } };
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
{ 
    var itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
    var newItem = announcementsList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

    newItem["Title"] = itemData[i,0]; newItem["LinkLocation"] = itemData[i,1];
    newItem.Update();
    context.ExecuteQuery(); // I can't remember if this needs to be called after each itme, or if you can just call it once after the loop.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example you are just creating a single list item.

Since CSOM supports [Request Batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798420.aspx) you could take advantage of it when creating multiple list items as demonstrated in the below example:

```
var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Contacts");
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    var itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation() { };
    var newItem = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
    newItem["Title"] = "New Contact" + (i+1);
    newItem.Update();    
 }
 context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

Before proceeding for adding the second item, you need to do an `Update` for the first item. In a way you need to do an update for each and every item you add.
P.S. You can run a `for` loop sort of thing to skip repetition of code lines.

EDIT - You may have a look at these links - [Link1](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/MS-SharePoint/Q_27720174.html) & [Link2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/24658e7d-ea7a-418e-9503-c87f81d3b449/adding-multiple-items-to-sharepoint-2010-list-programmatically?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please provide an example, i am quite new in coding.

Comment: The edit might help you.